# Mapping html form input to javascript object inside a newly formed element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, javascript-objects, jquery-ajaxq

I have the following html. Please have a look at it and I will explain the problem as and when we go along.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr id="<?php echo $record['id']?>" style="...">
   <td><?php echo $record['id']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $record['url']; ?></td>
   <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" onclick="edit(<?php echo ($record['id'])?>)"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What I am trying to achieve here is that when I click the "Edit" button, it clears that field and creates new empty fields in its place where those details can be entered again and in place of the edit button, the update button appears.

This is what the edit function looks like:

```
<script>
function edit(id){
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  $(element).empty();
  $(element).append("<td><input  name='id' value="+id+" disabled></td>" +
                    "<td><input type='text' name='url' ></td>" +
                    "<td><input type='text' name='title'></td>" +
                    "<td><input type='button' value='Update' onclick='testFunction()'></td>");
}
```

The update button fires a function called testFunction. Now in this testFunction, I want to send the new values into the new form that I have created with jQuery so that I can send those values to the MySQL so that the new value of title is updated for a given id.

Please look over the code and tell me how should I go about solving this?

```
var testFunction = function(newID){
        console.log("This is the NEW id of the object that we are changing----->");
        console.log(newID);
        console.log("--------------------------END------------------");
        $.post( "update", { id: newID})
            .done(function( ) {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
            });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: So do I understand correctly that the problem in your case is that you can't select the elements that are created dynamically with jQuery ?

Comment: @Artley .. The problem is I am not able to send the key-value of the new elements to a new function that fires through a button that I created as one of the new jQuery elements.

Comment: So could you please check the post method - it's looking for id : id and as I can see, should it be id : newID ?

Comment: I have corrected that. Anyway, that wasnt exactly the problem. I am able to send the newID. what I want is that I want to post the new url along with newID too. The new url that I entered in the jQuery elements that I created @Artley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//test record
var record = {
  id: 12345,
  title: 'Some title',
  url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45861223/edit'
};

function action(id) {
  var $element = $('#' + id),
    $title = $('[name=title]', $element),
    $url = $('[name=url]', $element),
    $btn = $('[type=button]', $element),
    isUpdate = ($btn.attr('value') != 'Edit');


  $title.prop('readOnly', isUpdate);
  $url.prop('readOnly', isUpdate);
  $btn.attr('value', isUpdate ? 'Edit' : 'Update');

  if (isUpdate) {
    // show some loading mask
    $.post("update", {
        title: $title.val(),
        url: $url.val(),
        id: id
      })
      .done(function() {
        // here you have the new id from the server
        // hide the loading mask
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="12345">
      <td><input type='text' name='title' value="Some title" readOnly></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='url' value="https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45861223/edit" readOnly></td>
      <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" onclick="action(12345)"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you fix the typo? Why are you confused?

Comment: Yes, I did. 

`var $element = $('#' + id);

        $title = $($element, '[name=title]');

        $url = $($element, '[name=url]');

        $btn = $($element, '[type=button]');

        isUpdate = ($btn.attr('value') != 'Edit');`

This is not doing anything. It's not showing any error but I am still not able to get these values. I am not a pro at jQuery/JS which is why I am getting confused

Comment: It should some things. 
1. Does it show as 2 readonly inputs and a button with Edit on it? 
2. Clicking on edit button make the inputs editable and change the text on the button from Edit to Update?
3. Clicking on the button make the inpuits readonly again and change the text from the button back to Edit?
4. Is there an ajax call made?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code. I had a few things written wrong. I made a test case that can run here also.